# Pyspark groupby and merge column values to get aggregated frequency of row count

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe like:

df:

```
id  name    subregion          streak
8103178 A   Western Asia         1
8103178 A   Southern Asia        1
8344002 B   North America        1
5225081 B   South America        1
5225081 C   Eastern Europe       1
5225081 D   Northern Europe      1
5225081 E   Southern Europe      1
5225081 F   South-Eastern Asia   1
5225081 G   Southern Africa      1
5225081 H   Central America      1
5225081 I   Northern Africa      1
5225081 I   Caribbean            2
5225081 J   Eastern Asia         2
8103178 A   Western Asia         3
8103178 A   Southern Asia        4
8344002 B   North America        5
5225081 B   South America        3
5225081 C   Eastern Europe       4
5225081 D   Northern Europe      3
5225081 E   Southern Europe      4
5225081 F   South-Eastern Asia   5
5225081 G   Southern Africa      3
5225081 H   Central America      4
5225081 I   Northern Africa      5
5225081 I   Caribbean            6
5225081 J   Eastern Asia         3
```

And I have a list distribution of regions like this:

```
'APAC'=['Southern Asia', 'South-Eastern Asia', 'Central Asia']
'EU/UK' = ['Western Europe', 'Eastern Europe', 'Northern Europe', 'Southern Europe']
'MEA'= ['Western Asia', 'Western Africa', 'Southern Africa', 'Northern Africa', 'Eastern Asia', 'Eastern Africa']
'NA'=['North America']
'LATAM' = ['Caribbean', 'Central America', 'South America']
```

What i want to do is to count the number of rows for every entry in 'subregion' of df which has value of 'streak'==1 and 'streak'=>3 and write it a new column while mapping the subregions to regions like this:

result:

[image]

I am new to pyspark. I can simply do a groupby and aggr function based on streak column and subregion. But mapping the subregion to region and create the result dataframe, I am looking for insights. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question, replace the images with text pls ? Currently, each person who would like to reproduce your case has to rewrite everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a table with the region/subregions informations :

```
df2.show()

+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|region|subregions                                                                                    |
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|APAC  |[Southern Asia, South-Eastern Asia, Central Asia]                                             |
|EU/UK |[Western Europe, Eastern Europe, Northern Europe, Southern Europe]                            |
|MEA   |[Western Asia, Western Africa, Southern Africa, Northern Africa, Eastern Asia, Eastern Africa]|
|NA    |[North America]                                                                               |
|LATAM |[Caribbean, Central America, South America]                                                   |
+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And then, it is a join + agg :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.join(F.broadcast(df2), F.expr("array_contains(subregions, subregion)")).groupBy(
    "region"
).agg(
    F.sum(F.when(F.col("streak").cast("int") == 1, 1)).alias("count_1"),
    F.sum(F.when(F.col("streak").cast("int") >= 3, 1)).alias("count_3+"),
).show()

+------+-------+--------+
|region|count_1|count_3+|
+------+-------+--------+
|   MEA|      3|       4|
|    NA|      1|       1|
| LATAM|      2|       3|
|  APAC|      2|       2|
| EU/UK|      3|       3|
+------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: I need to explore the F.broadcast function, very neatly done. Thanks Steven.

Comment: @Strayhorn you can ignore/remove it